# Amazon alexa app discover devices process?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

What process should be used to discover devices through the Amazon Alexa app? I can't find any related document regarding this process. Are there any account needs that must be associated with the list of devices? How does it find smart home devices and can that be controlled using voice commands?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the devices?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: hi @vinoth87 i'm also searching for somewhat similar question you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936085/how-to-add-our-own-smart-device-through-alexa-device-discovery). I even attended local Alexa Skill workshop but all they explain was App thing.. I asked them about hardware discovery but no was able to explain.. they said they will contact me latter with details.. lets see if i get any answer from them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my Echo Dot just yet (I'm in the UK) but I downloaded the Alexa App, signed in with my Amazon account, and it knew about the Fire TV stick that I have at home, as well as https://echosim.io/ which I've also used. I think any device that is associated with your Amazon account will be recognised.